# "Industrial Strength" C++ struct

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

It's been a while since I used C++. I was asked for job interview to create a C++ struct for a downsampling routine which would meet the following interface:

```
struct  deterministic_sample
{
    deterministic_rate( double rate );
    bool operator()();
};
```

-- with the following behaviour:

- We have an object of that class: `deterministic_sample s;`
- We call `s()` N times, and it returns `true`, M times. M / N is roughly equal to the rate
- The sequence is deterministic, not random and should be the same each time
- The class should be "industrial strength", for use on a busy stream.

My solution, version 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

struct deterministic_sample
{
    double sampRate;
    int index;

    deterministic_sample() {
        sampRate = 0.1;
        index = 0;
    }

    void deterministic_rate( double rate ) {
        this->sampRate = rate;  // Set the ivar. Not so necessary to hide data, but just complying with the interface, as given...
        this->index = 0;  // Reset the incrementer
    };

    bool operator()() {

        if (this->index == INT_MAX) {
            this->index = 0;
        }

        double multiple = this->index * this->sampRate;

        this->index++;  // Increment the index

        if (fmod(multiple, 1) < this->sampRate) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    };
};

int main()
{
    deterministic_sample s;  // Create a sampler
    s.deterministic_rate(0.253);  // Set the rate
    int tcnt = 0;  // Count of True
    int fcnt = 0;  // Count of False

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        bool o = s();
        if (o) {
            tcnt++;
        } else {
            fcnt++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Trues: " << tcnt << endl;
    cout << "Falses: " << fcnt << endl;

    cout << "Ratio: " << ((float)tcnt / (float)(tcnt + fcnt)) << endl;  // Show M / N

    return 0;
}
```

The interviewer said this v2 code "partly" addressed the requirements. v1 didn't have the constructor (my error), and didn't deal with overflow of the `int` ivar.

**What have I missed here to make this class robust/correct?** I think it is some aspect of "industrial strength" that I've missed.

ps. for any ethical types, I've already submitted my second-chance attempt... It's just bothering me to know why this was "partly"...

Comment: I have noticed in some of the "supplementary" text with the question, that the interviewer refers to the `rate` variable as a "constructor parameter". Perhaps, although I've met the requirements of the interface, I failed to account for this point about the constructor not taking a value. Have I misunderstood how constructors are specified in C++?

Comment: "M / N is roughly equal to the rate". What's "M"?

Comment: If `rate` was intended as a "constructor parameter," then the interface they gave you is written incorrectly, as it doesn't specify a constructor. It specifies a mutator.

Comment: Also, make your data private if it's for internal use only.

Comment: "industrial strength" is meaningless as a requirement.

Comment: Maybe they are looking for handling of negative rate or when rate > 1?

Comment: The interface is ill-formed, so can't be implemented. (If `deterministic_rate` is supposed to be a constructor it has the wrong name. If it's supposed to be a function it lacks a return type.)

Comment: The interviewer should have elaborated on what he/she didn't like

Comment: Yep - W was M. Must have had keyboard downsideup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems there are some improvements to the efficiency which could be made (certainly), that "industrial strength" has some implications though nothing concrete (possibly the problem...), or that the constructor was incorrectly named in the question (also possible).

In any case, no one has jumped on some glaring omission that I made to my constructor (like, I see there are two ways to do a C++ constructor; you should do both to be really bullet-proof, etc.)

I guess I'll just cross my fingers and hope I still progress to the soft-skills interview!
Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is far more complex than necessary. All you need to do is keep track of the current position, and return `true` when it goes past the threshold.

```
struct deterministic_sample
{
    double sampRate;
    double position;

    deterministic_sample() : sampRate(0.1), position(0.0) {
    }

    void deterministic_rate( double rate ) {
        assert(rate <= 1.0); // Only one output is allowed per input
        sampRate = rate;  // Set the ivar. Not so necessary to hide data, but just complying with the interface, as given...
        // No need to reset the position, it will work with changing rates
    };

    bool operator()() {
        position += sampRate;
        if (position < 1.0)
            return false;
        position -= 1.0;
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, cool - nice alternative. I hadn't thought of that implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unsigned` and integer overflow is a well-defined wraparound. This is very fast on normal CPU's.

The second problem I see is the mix of floating-point and integer math. That's not really efficient. It may be more efficient to store `multiple` as a member and just do `multiple += rate`. This saves you one integer to double conversion.

However, the `fmod` is still quite expensive. You can avoid that by keeping `int trueSoFar` instead. Now the rate so far is `double(trueSoFar)/double(index)` and you can check `double(trueSoFar)/double(index) > rate` or more efficiently `trueSoFar> int(index * rate)`. As we already saw, `rate*index` can be replaced by `multiple += rate`.

This means we have one double addition (`multiple +=`), one FP to int conversion `int(multiple)` and one integer comparison.

[edit]
You can also avoid FP math altogether by keeping a 32/32 rational approximation of `rate`, and comparing that to the realised rate (again stored as a 32/32 ratio). Since `a/b > c/d` when `a*d > b*c` you can use a 64 bit multiply here. Even better, for the target ratio you can choose 2^32 as a fixed denominator (i.e. `unsigned long targetRate = rate*pow(2^32)`, b=2^32 implicit) so that you now have `unsigned long(unsigned long long(a)*index) >> 32) > trueSoFar`. Even on a 32 bit CPU, this is fairly quick. `>>32` is a no-op there.

Comment: Also, `fmod(x, 1)` can be replaced by `fabs(x - ((long) x))` (or simply `x - long(x)` if `x` is guaranteed positive), which is much faster.

Comment: `x - long(x)` still is a FP-to-int followed by an int-to-FP conversion, and then a FP sub. Just calculating the argument to `fabs` is already slower than my proposal.

Comment: Ouch, you're right. `x  - ceil(x)` might work, but then your proposal is still better.

Comment: OK, good suggestion too. I read that `int` wraparound wasn't so well defined, and since I already had the int from the first version I just adapted it -- should've looked a little farther...